# How to parse SOAP XML in ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="https://extranet.mcs.be/DEV_QUALITY_API/modules/quality/services/soap/quality.php"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <ns1:getQuestionnairesListResponse>
  <return SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:QuestionnaireListItem[34]"
   xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfQuestionnaireListItem">
   <item xsi:type="ns1:QuestionnaireListItem">
    <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">0000000022</ID>
    <Code xsi:type="xsd:string">Interest PubTransp</Code>
    <Reference xsi:type="xsd:string">Check Employees Interest in Public
     Transport</Reference>
   </item>
   <item xsi:type="ns1:QuestionnaireListItem">
    <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">0000000008</ID>
    <Code xsi:type="xsd:string">CS SRE North 2003</Code>
    <Reference xsi:type="xsd:string">Customer Satisfaction SRE North 2003</Reference>
   </item>
   <item xsi:type="ns1:QuestionnaireListItem">
    <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">0000000006</ID>
    <Code xsi:type="xsd:string">CS SRE South 2003</Code>
    <Reference xsi:type="xsd:string">Customer Satisfaction SRE South 2003</Reference>
   </item>
.
.
.
```

I want to parse the above soap String (I actually want to get items from the above soap). How could I do this?

Comment: You may want to look at the Savon gem: https://github.com/rubiii/savon

Comment: @MichaelKohl I'd have put this as an answer...

Comment: @BenoitGarret: it seemed a bit too much like an RTFM-type answer. Anyway, I posted it now.

Answer (score 3):

There's a gem called [Savon](https://github.com/rubiii/savon) that's specifically made for dealing with SOAP in Ruby.

There's good documentation on [the web site](http://savonrb.com/), once you looked into that and have more specific questions I'm sure we can help you.